# How do you solve the equation $ax\equiv b \pmod m$ with the extended Euclidean algorithm?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

How do you solve the equation $ax\equiv b \pmod m$ with the extended Euclidean algorithm?

I saw that you could solve the Diophantine equation $ax-my=b$

I've seen examples but I'm still a bit confused. (Sorry if this sounds stupid)

Comment: this is equivalent of finding the inverse of a mod m

Comment: what you need explanation for?

Comment: How to find the inverse

Comment: See my answers in the linked dupes for a couple worked examples (among other methods).

Comment: The easiest way to use the classical extended Euclidean algorithm (to get the Bezout equation hence the fraction $\,x\equiv a/b)$ is [this **forward** methoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242). $\,x\,$ uniquely exists $\bmod m \iff\gcd(b,m)= 1\ \ $